# Four (4) Sub Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Is there any possible way to do this kind of sub query:

```
DELETE (INSERT (SELECT (INSERT)))
```

I know how to: `INSERT (SELECT)`:

```
INSERT INTO r (u_id,role) 
    VALUES ((SELECT u_id FROM USER WHERE email="mumair1992@gmail.com"),'Agent');
```

My problem is:
User is present in request table when he verifies his account, system must have to:

1. Create user in user table
2. Create user role in role table
3. Delete user from request table

Comment: Why can't you just do 3 queries? It would certainly be a lot more readable than all those sub queries (even if that were possible)

Comment: Why not use a stored procedure as the interface? Then you can do all the checks, insert/deletes and handle errors too.

Comment: thank you sir.@DavidG i am already doing this with 3 queries
thank you sir.@jpw ill keep procedures in mind next time... i am doing my Final Project just started learning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can do `INSERT INTO .... SELECT ...` is that the `SELECT` is being used as the input into the `INSERT` query.

However, an `INSERT` query doesn't return anything in that way. You are much better off just writing 3 distinct queries like this:

```
--Create user in user table
INSERT INTO UserTable VALUES (...)

--Create user role in role table
INSERT INTO UserRoles VALUES (...)

--Delete user from request table
DELETE FROM Requests WHERE ...
```

You could even wrap that all in a transaction to ensure all or none of the queries run:

```
BEGIN TRAN

--Create user in user table
INSERT INTO UserTable VALUES (...)

--Create user role in role table
INSERT INTO UserRoles VALUES (...)

--Delete user from request table
DELETE FROM Requests WHERE ...

COMMIT
```

I suspect also that you are wanting to use the ID of the user that you've created. To do this, assuming your `UserTable` has an `IDENTITY` column, you can use the [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function:

```
BEGIN TRAN

--Create user in user table
INSERT INTO UserTable VALUES (...)

DECLARE @UserID INT
SET @UserID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

--Create user role in role table
INSERT INTO UserRoles (UserID, RoleID) VALUES (@UserID, ...)

--Delete user from request table
DELETE FROM Requests WHERE ...

COMMIT
```

Comment: @user3316447 Regarding your suggested edit on this answer, I would have accepted `BEGIN TRAN` being rewritten as `BEGIN TRANSACTION` (though I prefer the shorter one as it's easier to type) but the semicolons at the end of each line are not needed in SQL Server.